# What is the difference between /sys/block/sda1/stat and /sys/block/xvda1/stat?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, sysfs

On my local machine, I have `/sys/block/sda1/stat`.
On an Amazon machine, I have `/sys/block/xvda1/stat`.

When I run `cat /sys/block/sda1/stat` or `cat /sys/block/xvda1/stat` both give 11 fields of output.

What is the difference between `/sys/block/sda1/stat` and `/sys/block/xvda1/stat` files?

Comment: You can see difference between two files by using `diff` command, by the way.

Comment: @ MatthewRock did u understand my question ?

Comment: Yes. That's why I said "by the way". You ran cat on both files, so you probably have tried comparing them. I just said that diff might be more useful than comparing it manually. I'm not answering your question, just throwing in a comment.

Comment: @ MatthewRock Better look at the answer. don't comment anything without understanding. i know `diff` command ok.

Comment: I've looked at the answer. If you didn't want to compare files contents, you shouldn't have used `cat`. If you show that you used `cat` to see contents of both files, it indicates your intention to compare their contents, in which case `diff` is more effective. However, because I knew that your question was referring to something else, I didn't post it as the answer(because it clearly isn't), I just commented on your action showing that it can be done more effectively. Honestly I can't see a problem with that.

Comment: Sometimes I really want to be able to down-vote a comment.

Comment: Did you really have `/sys/block/sda1/stat` instead of `/sys/block/sda/stat`? As far as I know, the `stat` file should be per device, not per partition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/sys` directory is generally where the [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) filestystem is mounted, which contains information about devices and other kernel information.

The files in `/sys/block` contain information about block devices on your system.  Your local system has a block device named `sda`, so `/sys/block/sda` exists.  Your Amazon instance has a device named `xvda`, so `/sys/block/xvda` exists.

The `/sys/block/<dev>/stat` file provides several statistics about the state of block device `<dev>`. It consists of a single line of text containing 15 decimal values separated by whitespace:

```
Name            units         description
----            -----         -----------
read I/Os       requests      number of read I/Os processed
read merges     requests      number of read I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
read sectors    sectors       number of sectors read
read ticks      milliseconds  total wait time for read requests
write I/Os      requests      number of write I/Os processed
write merges    requests      number of write I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
write sectors   sectors       number of sectors written
write ticks     milliseconds  total wait time for write requests
in_flight       requests      number of I/Os currently in flight
io_ticks        milliseconds  total time this block device has been active
time_in_queue   milliseconds  total wait time for all requests
discard I/Os    requests      number of discard I/Os processed
discard merges  requests      number of discard I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
discard sectors sectors       number of sectors discarded
discard ticks   milliseconds  total wait time for discard requests
```

So, each block device will have its own `stat`istics file, hence the different values.
See [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt) for more details.

Comment: Am agree with your ans.

Comment: Can you please tel me how do i find block device name in different machine?

Comment: Well, you can look at the names of directories in `/sys/block`.

Comment: Also, `find /dev -type b`.

Comment: No worries.  I had left this out as an RTFM issue, but I guess it's fine to have it here.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The question, explicitly, asked what the difference was between these files.  OP did *not* ask what the content of the files indicated.

Answer (score 3):

Both files contain the statistics of the first partition (/sys/block/sda**1**/stat) of the first device (/sys/block/sd**a**1/stat) found by a particular driver or subsystem.  The difference is the driver.

Your amazon VM is using the Xen driver (/sys/block/**xvd**a1/stat).
Your local machine is using the SCSI driver (/sys/block/**sd**a1/stat).

xvd = Xen Virtual Disk

sd = SCSI Disk

Comment: Worth noting WHY the names are different.

Comment: That was, from what I understood, the question.